# What conditions must be met for Straight in Approach minimums to be published?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, approach, localizer

Looking at KSEE LOC-D approach, the final course is pretty much lined up with the runway. The MDA leaves you about 1200 AGL.
I'm thinking only circling minimums are published because it would be a very steep descent, but what is the criterion for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why and how would I land straight-in from a circle-to-land approach?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/75622/why-and-how-would-i-land-straight-in-from-a-circle-to-land-approach) (the question is different, but I think the answers given cover yours too).

Comment: Yes that section in the AIM was what I was looking for. It just says when "the normal rate of descent or the runway alignment factor of 30 deg. (15 deg for GPS IAPs) is exceeded"